# Date calculation method for Java

Tags: java, arrays, localdate

I have a delivery project which consists the class names below:

FoodItem
Location
Route
Store
Vehicle
Warehouse
Launcher(Includes main method)

What I need to do next is: I have initialized an object called "Oatmeal" for the FoodItem class.

This FoodItem has 4 attributes as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class FoodItem {
    public String label;
    private double volume;
    private double weight;
    private LocalDate expirationDate;
```

The values for those attributes have been set in Launcher as follows:

```
FoodItem oatmeal = new FoodItem("Serving size is 1/2 Cup 40gr");
oatmeal.setVolume(25);
oatmeal.setWeight(0.500);
oatmeal.setExpirationDate(LocalDate.of(2025,2,5));
```

Now what I need to do is calculate the date to check if the product's expiration date is still valid with the logic of **(Expiration Date - Today's Date + 3 Days)** For that I've created a method called stillValid as follows:

```
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.time.LocalDate;

private boolean stillValid(FoodItem foodItem){
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate dayLeft = date.plus(Period.ofDays(3));
        if(foodItem.getExpirationDate() != dayLeft) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now I need to use this method inside of my addItem method in order to check if the Item's expiration date is not passed, I can add to the store.

```
public void addItem(FoodItem foodItem) { 
        int stop = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < foodItemsArray.length; i++) {
            if (foodItemsArray[i] != null) {        
                stop = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (stop == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < foodItemsArray.length; i++) {
                if (foodItemsArray[i] != foodItem) {
                    foodItemsArray[i] = foodItem;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this part, I couldn't create the logic in my mind to have my stillValid fuction inside of addItem body, or even if I did the method stillValid correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want >= or > instead of !=, with != the stillValid only return false when you're exactly 3 days before expiry, down to the milisecond.

Comment: "Now I need to use this method inside of my addItem method in order to check if the Item's expiration date is not passed, I can add to the store." <- And what is the requirement when the check is negative? Should it just not add the item without any feedback, should it throw an Exception? In short: What do you want your addItem method to do when an item is passed to it that is no longer valid?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS If the check is negative it doesn't include the item to the array.

Comment: @Martheen When I try to use <= or < it gives me error such "Operator '<=' cannot be applied to 'java.time.LocalDate', 'java.time.LocalDate'

Comment: Use the `isBefore` method of your `LocalDate` (or `isAfter`).

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Peruse the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) Javadoc to discover handy methods, such as `isAfter` and `plusDays`.

```
LocalDate.now().isAfter( this.getExpirationDate().plusDays( 3 ) ) ;
```

## Details

Add a `stillValid` or `expired` method to your `FoodItem` class, if that is the reasonable place to know the rule of adding three days to expiration date.

For comparing `LocalDate`, use `isAfter` and `isBefore`.

```java
public boolean expired ()
{
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;  // Consider specifying a time zone here.
    Period gracePeriod = Period.ofDays( 3 ) ;
    LocalDate finalExpiration = this.getExpirationDate().plus( gracePeriod ) ;
    boolean isExpired = today.isAfter( finalExpiration ) ;
    return isExpired ;
}
```

Or, more simply:

```java
public boolean expired ()
{
    return LocalDate.now().isAfter( this.getExpirationDate().plusDays( 3 ) ) ;
}
```

Usage:

```
if( ! foodItem.expired() ) { myList.add( foodItem ) ; }
```

**Caveat:** Note that for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. Right now it is “tomorrow” in Tokyo, Japan while still “yesterday” in Toronto, Canada. By omitting the `ZoneId` argument when calling `LocalDate.now`, your results will vary depending on the deployment JVM’s current default time zone. As suggested in the comment, consider using [`LocalDate#now( ZoneId zone )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) e.g. `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )`.

### Full example class

Here is an example class using the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature [new in Java 16](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/records.html).

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.Objects;

public record FoodItem(String label , double volume , double weight , LocalDate expirationDate , Period gracePeriod)
{
    // Constructor.
    public FoodItem ( final String label , final double volume , final double weight , final LocalDate expirationDate , final Period gracePeriod )
    {
        this.label = Objects.requireNonNull( label );
        this.volume = Objects.requireNonNull( volume );
        this.weight = Objects.requireNonNull( weight );
        this.expirationDate = Objects.requireNonNull( expirationDate );
        this.gracePeriod = Objects.requireNonNull( gracePeriod );
        if ( this.gracePeriod.isNegative() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The grace period must be positive. Message # f511c804-db04-4783-8329-3a8e928b98cf." ); }
    }

    // Calculated value. 
    public boolean isExpired ( )
    {
        return LocalDate.now().isAfter( this.expirationDate().plus( this.gracePeriod ) );
    }
}
```

Usage.

```java
FoodItem oats = new FoodItem( "Oats" , 25d , 0.500d , LocalDate.of( 2025 , Month.FEBRUARY , 5 ) , Period.ofDays( 3 ) );
System.out.println( "oats = " + oats );
System.out.println( "Is oats expired: " + oats.isExpired() );
```

When run.

```
oats = FoodItem[label=Oats, volume=25.0, weight=0.5, expirationDate=2025-02-05, gracePeriod=P3D]
Is oats expired: false
```

Comment: To me this looks like exactly the answer the OP needs, thanks. It may be worth mentioning that `isAfter` means *is strictly after*, so the item will be reported expired starting from day 4 after the expiration date.

Comment: I had purposefully used `US/Eastern` in my edit . Last week, I was looking for something in one of the most popular books on Java when I came across: *We prefer the US/Eastern time zone to America/ New_York since it is more general. There are so many time zones because there is a lot of duplication. When writing code, try to use whatever is clearest. In the United States, most people say “eastern” when talking about east coast time, so we like to use that in the code.*

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash (a) `US/Eastern` is deprecated, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). (b) `US/Eastern` is not "more general" — `US/Eastern` is mapped to `America/New_York`. (c) As for duplication in time zones, that may be so *now*, but the various zones are usually created because of divergence at some point in the past or future. There are rare mistakes, such as `America/Montreal` which turns out to have been added thinking it had diverged at some point but actually had not. And so is now deprecated, linking to `America/Toronto`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Regarding "In the United States, most people say “eastern” when talking about east coast time" — that is a problem in the culture that really needs fixing. There is no such thing as "Eastern" time, and saying "Eastern time" only clouds the issue rather than clarifies.

Comment: Good to know. It was the first time today when I used `US/Eastern` and that coincidently was while editing your answer . I will revert to using `America/New_York` as I had been doing earlier. Thanks for sharing this valuable information.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Three million Americans in [Puerto Rico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Puerto_Rico) might differ in their opinion on what "US/Eastern" time should mean. ;-)